# The while loop wont loop and the program ends on the last printf statement...any ideas why?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

```
while(play == 'y' || play == 'Y')
{
            do
            {
                    printf("Max number of guesses is %d\n", count);
                    printf("What is your guess? It must be between 1 and %d\n", $
                    scanf("%d", &guess);

                    if(guess > randNum)
                    {
                            printf("Too large!\n");
                            count = count -1;
                    }
                    else if(guess < randNum)
                    {
                            printf("Too small!\n");
                            count = count -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            printf("%s, you guessed my number!\n", name);
                            yourNum = guess;
                    }
            } while(yourNum != guess || count == 0);

            printf("Play again? (y/n)\n");
            scanf("%c", &play);
```

Comment: Blind guess: `scanf("%c", &play);` should be `scanf(" %c", &play);`.

Comment: flagged as off topic because it's asking for debugging help.

Comment: Shouldn't `while(yourNum != guess || count == 0);` be `while(count > 0 && yourNum != guess);` ?

Comment: @BetaCarotin is right.  You would be looping even after `count` reaches 0 and the user haven't guessed it right.

Comment: yeah i was just looking at that 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to 'do while' for first while loop also so that user will be able to play once .My assumption is play variable is not initialized with 'y' or 'Y' that's why while loop is not getting executed.more code is required . My suggestion will look like this`

```
            do{
do
            {
                    printf("Max number of guesses is %d\n", count);
                    printf("What is your guess? It must be between 1 and %d\n", $
                    scanf("%d", &guess);

                    if(guess > randNum)
                    {
                            printf("Too large!\n");
                            count = count -1;
                    }
                    else if(guess < randNum)
                    {
                            printf("Too small!\n");
                            count = count -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            printf("%s, you guessed my number!\n", name);
                            yourNum = guess;
                    }
            } while(yourNum != guess || count == 0);

            printf("Play again? (y/n)\n");
            scanf("%c", &play);
 }while(play == 'y' || play == 'Y')
```

Comment: No, No, the problem was the `'\n'` that remained in the input buffer after `scanf("%c", &play);`, was read and taken the next iteration as `play`, the test then failed `('\n' == 'y' || '\n' == 'Y')` causing the loop the exit. Changing the `scanf` format string to `" %c"` caused `scanf` to skip **all whitespace** (including `newlines`) resolving the problem. It had nothing whatsoever to do with where the test clause was located. (no downvote, but I would suggest you work on a fix)